# ScrollBar not Appearing

Tags: c#, xaml, arcgis, infowindow, esri

I am having problems getting the scrollbars to show in my InfoWindow. Code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

XAML:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyFeatureLayerInfoWindowTemplate">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}" Grid.Column="0" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

<esri:InfoWindow x:Name="MyInfoWindow"
                 CornerRadius="20"
                 ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyFeatureLayerInfoWindowTemplate}"
                 Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"
                 MouseLeftButtonUp="MyInfoWindow_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                 ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                 Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"
                 MaxHeight="200"
                 MaxWidth="200"/>
```

C#:

```
if (clickpoint != lastPoint)
{
    MyInfoWindow.Anchor = clickpoint;
    MyInfoWindow.Content = e.Graphic.Attributes;
    MyInfoWindow.IsOpen = true;
    lastPoint = clickpoint;
}
```

Picture of what I am seeing:

[image]

The content appears in the InfoWindow, but the scrollbars are nowhere to be found. Hopefully it is something simple, I feel like I have tried everything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry I posted web info I saw earlier but have you tried putting it inside of a parent container and setting the defined height and width there? Something like a dockpanel or stackpanel

Comment: Try adding a `<RowDefinition Height="400"/>`. I think your Grid now auto-shrinks to fit.

Comment: Where should I add a RowDefinition? In my Template?

Comment: @Bearcat9425 wrapping it in a stackpanel did not work :(

Comment: Row Definition should be added where you Column Definitions are, and dang :(, quick question though did you take the defined height and width off the infowindow and put it on the stack panel or leave it as is?

Comment: <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="400"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

Comment: Just tried it... Also did not work... I don't understand what is going on with this thing

Comment: Are you using the example from this site here. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/samples/index.html#//02q2000000n9000000

Comment: Yes I am.  My data is much larger than one word though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyFeatureLayerInfoWindowTemplate">
  <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Keys}" Grid.Column="0" />
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Values}" Grid.Column="1" />
    </Grid>
  </ScrollViewer>
</DataTemplate>
```

I mean: wrap the grid inside a ScrollViewer

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you :)